# This.rpc.getBalance is not a function

Tags: taquito

I have a problem during the call to view the balance of an address. I'm following the various tutorials and the following error is raised: `this.rpc.getBalance is not a function` and it does not return any value.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to this issue: https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/issues/730

You first need to create an instance of TezosToolkit using the RPC URL of your choice.

example:

```
import { TezosToolkit } from '@taquito/taquito';

const Tezos = new TezosToolkit('https://api.tez.ie/rpc/edonet');
const balance = await Tezos.tz.getBalance('tz3gP1z15b656zk9WX42bTyCkpKAm6QA6YKo');
console.log(`${balance.toNumber() / 1000000} ꜩ`);
```

If that doesn't solve the issue, can you paste some of your code here? It might help find out what the problem is.

Comment: Agreed, I'd bet he needs to access the .tz member: rpc.tz.getBalance().

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help the code works, the only difference from mine was that I called new TezosToolkit (**{rpc: 'api_address'}**) ... which causes the error.
however I entered the code in a try ... catch statement and on the first call it does not read the balance and reports an error: **"Request to https://api.tez.ie/rpc/edonet/chains/main/blocks/head / context / contracts // balance failed "**.
on the other hand, a second call(click on connect button) reads the balance correctly.
i put an 'alter-ego' on codesandbox at this address: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-platform-g4id1?file=/src/App.js